# How would you hand a member of a class implementing an interface to another class using the interface?

Tags: c++, inheritance, interface, encapsulation

I was just experimenting with interfaces and wrapping classes and I have come across a roadblock.  I am wrapping an SFML::RenderWindow in a class that implements a draw() function.  For example:

```
struct ISprite {
    ....
    functions for sprites...
    ....
}

class SFML_Sprite : public ISprite
{
public:
    ....
    functions implementing stuff for sprites
    ....

private:
    sf::Sprite mSprite;

} 

struct IWindow {
    ...
    virtual void draw(const ISprite& sprite) = 0;
    ...
}

class SFML_Window : public IWindow
{
public:
    ...
    void draw(const ISprite& sprite)
    {
         //This is where the problem is.  Is there a way for me to get to
         //mSprite? 
         mWin.draw(sprite.mSprite);
    }
private:
    sf::RenderWindow mWin;
}
```

In other words, is there a way for me to pass the underlying stuff around?  A pattern I am missing?  I am basically trying to hide the windows and sprite implementations.  Eventually, I would like to try 'swapping' implementations and go a little lower level, but if I can't figure this out, I am no where near ready to try that.

Thanks!

Comment: Oh - I am trying to avoid casting.  I think that might work, have not checked yet, but would like to not have to if I could....

Comment: Does `Isprite` have a member named `mSprite`?

Comment: I might dare to say that inheritance is the wrong tool for the job. `IWindow` says it works for all kinds of sprite, and so `SFML_Window : IWindow` also promises that it will work for all kinds of sprite. But it doesn't appear like it does. Perhaps you should be using templates: `template<typename Sprite> struct IWindow { ... }; class SMFL_Window : public IWindow<SFML_Sprite> { ... };`

Comment: @cigien - no - it doesn't.  I was just trying to illustrate that is what I was trying to achieve.  I am trying to 'hide' the sfml bits in a wrapper or interface so I can eventually change the implementation

Comment: @HTNW I was able to get it to work by making SFML_Window::draw a friend of SFML_Sprite and using a static_cast:
 mWindow.draw(static_cast<SFMLSpriteImpl::SFML_Sprite*>(&sprite)->mSprite);
but that feels all sorts of wrong.  I'll give the template idea a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you want to do the cast? It's safe and well defined in this context:

```
class ISprite {
};

class SFML_Sprite : public ISprite
{
};

class IWindow {
public:
    virtual void draw(const ISprite& sprite) = 0;
};

class SFML_Window : public IWindow
{
public:
    void draw(const ISprite& _sprite)
    {
       auto sprite = static_cast<const SFML_Sprite&>(_sprite);
    }
};

int main() {
   SFML_Window i;
   IWindow &a = i;

   SFML_Sprite x;
   ISprite &y = x;

   a.draw(y);
   return 0;
}
```

You can use dynamic_cast if you want to pay for a runtime check to ensure you're really getting the right type, but you always should be as you're not going to be mixing two different graphics backends in the same code.

Comment: Largely because it didn't "feel right", but in this context, it probably is ok. Ultimately, I would like to experiment with my own code, making windows from xcb, opengl, and move up to vulkan, etc - which I would then write so that casts aren't necessary because that would be like a level or two below sfml.  I also wanted to experiment with writing shared libraries to swap functionality, and rendering was one case where I thought of that it was both used and fun.  Thanks!